# How to automatically send user to newline when line runs out in TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

[image]

```
 TextFormField(
        style: loginText,
        obscureText: obs,
        textAlignVertical: const TextAlignVertical(y: 0.2),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintMaxLines: 2,
          prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
          hintText: hint,
          prefixIconColor: orange,
          hintStyle: loginText,
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: 1.5,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(
              color: orange,
              width: 1.5,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I have a textFormField widget that I created myself. As seen in the image, there is a feature that I want a few lines to be written. But I couldn't find how to do this in TextFormField.

When I use the maxLines, minLines terms, '!obscureText || maxLines == 1': Obscured fields cannot be multiline.' i am getting the error. I set KeyboardType to multiline. However, this feature does not automatically switch the user to a new line when the end of the line is reached, if the user presses the enter key on the phone. What I'm trying to do is for the user to switch to a new line when the line ends.

Answer (score 1):

you can set `maxLines` to `null` or higher than 1 value, this setting lets your `TextFormField` that expands vertically but attention to this sentence that **Obscured fields cannot be multiline**.
and you can use `obs` as a bool to have a condition even for `maxLines`.

```
TextFormField(
  maxLines: obs ? 1 : null,
  style: loginText,
  obscureText: obs,
  textAlignVertical: const TextAlignVertical(y: 0.2),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
    hintText: hint,
    prefixIconColor: orange,
    hintStyle: loginText,
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(
        color: Colors.grey,
        width: 1.5,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(
        color: orange,
        width: 1.5,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
  ),
),
```

happy coding...

Comment: '!obscureText || maxLines == 1': Obscured fields cannot be multiline.' i am getting the error.

Comment: that is exactly true,  I you want to use Obscured you should notice that Obscured fields cannot be multiline. attention to my Edited answer.